# In textarea entered single quote of crying smiley live replacing with jquery str.replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I had a similar question when creating and replacing the crying smiley `:'(` with php. I found a solution there with some support. Now I have the same issue with my Jquery function.

When sending a chat message the message is sent to the server and entered into a database, but at the same time the message is pushed into the chat window with jQuery `.html(newMessage)'

To replace the smiley shortcuts in `newMessage` I got the following function (short version)

```
 function replaceSmileys(message){
    return message
    .replace(":-)","<a title=':-)'><i class='smiley smile'></i></a>")
    .replace(":)","<a title=':-)'><i class='smiley smile'></i></a>")
    .replace(":(","<a title=':-('><i class='smiley sad'></i></a>")
    .replace(":-(","<a title=':-('><i class='smiley sad'></i></a>")
    .replace(":')","<a title=\":'(\"><i class='smiley crying'></i></a>")
    .replace(':\')',"<a title=\":'(\"><i class='smiley crying'></i></a>")
    .replace(":&#39;(","<a title=\":'(\"><i class='smiley crying'></i></a>");
}
```

Everything is replaced fine but my 3 attempts to replace the crying smiley `:'(` all fail

Anyone a similar issue? Again, there are many issues with single quotes and Javascript here to read through, but I can't find the right answer.

Thanks in advance for your efforts...

Comment: Why not `.replace(":'(","<a title=\":'(\"><i class='smiley crying'></i></a>");`

Comment: That is correct, can I delet my question? I need a break I think :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are escaping the wrong character. Try this:

```
replace(":'(","<a title=':\'('><i class='smiley crying'></i></a>")
```

Comment: Looks like I need a break :-)

Comment: Yes this worked. The problem was caused by a typo, using the closing bracket `)` instead of the opening `(`.

Comment: They didn't delete the question... Although I marks for moderator revision. Anyway... so I give you the green check pointing out my typo :-)